# Download file in a gwt application

Tags: java, gwt, download

I am new in gwt. I need to create a link in my web application where the user will
download a file that is in my server. How can I get a file from db and save it in server and then alow user to dowanload it?
I was searching for something in the web, but I could not find
something about.
Is there any GWT tool that allow me to develop a link in my
application to make a download from the server to the client?
Or another way that you guys use to do?

Comment: @cdbitesky I understand this question to be download, your link is for upload.

Answer (score 0):

Copy from DB to server is a server side action: implement in your servlet or RPC triggered by your user click on the link.

To download the file to client, then I suppose you could simply return a link to where you copied the file on your server -- of course it has to be in a public/accessible place.  Depending upon your file type and what you want to happen exactly, you may need to further process, but you'd have to define first what you exactly want to accomplish.  For instance, you may need to parse or stream the file to return its raw content to the browser.

Comment: if i return a link to where i copied the file on my server (in a public place), so i can't conbtrol the access of files and other users, i want to limit users and give access to files for downloading. so it's a good idea that i store files in db? how can i store them in file server with download access limit?

Comment: I don't believe storing file in DB helps in any way, I am no expert but I would not do that.  If your file is stored in a private place on the server then your application control who has access to it -- I suppose your app has authentication in place.  However, you may have to stream the file content to transfer it from server to client.  For the link option to work, you would have to dynamically modify server access rights so that the specific user would have access to the file,  not the public by default.  I don't know how to implement such a strategy, I have never done it.